# dyld library not loaded - PHP, Laravel, Composer command line commands not working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homebrew, dyld

I updated my PHP version to 7.2 via homebrew and now any laravel,php, and composer command brings this error. I've googled the error though no luck! What do I need to install? Why has this now became an error?

`libldap-2.4.2.dylib`

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it - 
I ran....

```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openldap/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openldap/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openldap/include"
```

Then after words a similar error came up that libiconv was not loaded and did not match the PHP version I had, so I ran...

```
brew install libiconv
```

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, I found that .bash_profile php path was reference to /usr/local/opt/ instead of XAMPP.

```
which php
```

Try above command to see current php path. If it not proper, set the right one, such as:

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a little different, I installed php 8.1 (previously I had 7.4) with brew but it didn't link so I had to run the link command

```
brew link php@8.1
```

Then

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

and it's solved :D